# Change my Nuxt.js host from IP to domain name

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I started a small project using Nuxt.js on my own ubuntu VPS and I would like to change my host from the IP to the domain name, because right now when I do `npm run dev` i get the `IP:PORT.`
How can I replace `IP:PORT` by my domain name directly like that **mydomain.com**
By the way my domain name already point on my VPS server.

This is my `nuxt.config.js` file :

```
server: {
  port: 8000, // default: 3000
  host: '0.0.0.0' // default: localhost
}
```

Comment: You will need to forward the port you want to access your website on and then access like yourwebsite.com:8888 where 8888 is the port